# FATAL EXCEPTION : main and Nullpointer

Tags: java, android

I've had this really annoying problem for a couple of days, and I cannot quite seem to solve it. I am trying to open a `.csv` file, so I imported it into the `res/raw/` folder of my project. Then I am trying to open and read it via the `getResources()` method, and that's exactly where I get the `NullPointerException`. Here's the method that reads the file and fills an array with the available lines.

Here's my `Activity` where I create an Object `newwords` from the class `Words`, and then I want to call the `PlayWithRawFiles()` method from class `Words`.

```
public class Swear_Activity extends Activity implements OnInitListener, OnClickListener {

    private Words newwords;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swear);
    }
    public void onClick(View view){
        try {
            newwords.PlayWithRawFiles();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("greshka");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

now this is the class where i get the error

```
public class Words{

    public Word[] wordsArray;
    private String locale = "de";
    
    public Words(String locale) {
        if (locale != null ) {
            this.locale = locale;
        }
    }
    
    Context c;
    public void PlayWithRawFiles() throws IOException  {
        String str="";
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();          
        int i = 0;
        InputStream is = c.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.est);
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try{
            if (is != null) reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println ("ss");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            
        if (is!=null) {                         
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                Word wd = new Word(1,"str");
                this.wordsArray[i] = wd;
                i++;
            }               
        }       
        is.close();
    }
}
```

here is class Word

```
public class Word {
    private int type;
    private String data;

    public Word(int type, String data){
        this.type = type;
        this.data=data;
    }

    public int getType(){
        return this.type;
    }
    public String getData(){
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

Here is the Stack Trace

> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647): java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647): at de.android.swearapp.Swear_Activity.onClick(Swear_Activity.java:32)
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647):     at >android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>
> 07-10 13:28:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(647):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

What have I done wrong? I'm really stuck at this one. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I see here,

- You are not instantiating `newwords` as in `newwords = new Words("")`;
- `c` is null and not assigned a context.

I recommend you re-code the class like this:

```
public class Words{
   public Word[] wordsArray;
   private String locale = "de";
   private Context c;
   public Words(String locale, Context paramContext) {
      if (locale != null ) {
         this.locale = locale;
      }
      c = paramContext;
   }
// Rest of code ok.
//
// Remove the Context c variable further on as it is declared above!
}
```

What is done is, we simply added the `Context` as part of the constructor for the class `Words`. Then to instantiate the class `Words` do this, from your `SwearActivity` class:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    newwords = new Words("", getApplicationContext());
    try {
        newwords.PlayWithRawFiles();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("greshka");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You never instantiated newwords object.

You need to add something like this in your onCreate before the onClick

```
newwords = new Words("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not giving `Context c` (in `Words`) an actual value, so `c.getResources()` will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: Good catch, I missed that one. It will need to be fixed too.